# unable to get this syntax in JavaScript, defining and calling method immediately in xmlhttprequest onload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, onload

Unable to get vanilla JavaScript syntax or maybe I have brainfreeze.

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onload = function() {
console.log('hello');
}
xhttp.open("GET", "my data.txt");
xhttp.send();
```

The onload function is defined and called immediately, why don't we need to call it seperately after defining like other normal functions?

Comment: Your console.log is missing one single qoute in the end

Comment: It is NOT called immediately. It is a callback eventHandler and is executed AFTER the send on successful call. Please  [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/load_event)

Comment: And please also read [Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers)